# Mix Portrait and Landscape Pages in the Same Access Report

Tags: ms-access, report, landscape, portrait

I have a landscape report in Access 2013 where I want to add a portrait header page (first page in the report) and glossary page (last page in the report).

Any clue?

Regards

Comment: Not a chance, I'd say. You'll have to create separate reports and combine the output into one PDF or so. -- Personal note: different page orientations in one document are annoying. Why not make everything landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Send the report to WORD and use VBA to set the orientation of each section.

Still new at using Access VBA to create/alter Word, but used a command like the one below.  I had a letter (portrait) but had to create a table on the second page (section) that was oriented as landscape.

```
oWord = getobject(,"word.application)

oWord.activedocument.pagesetup.Orientation = wdorientportrait
```